# Eclipse format question

Tags: eclipse, formatting, coding-style, code-readability

When I format in eclipse long lines become from this :

```
String str = instance.someMethod("jhdajhajsha").someOtherMethod("sakjsaksja");
```

to this :

```
String str = instance.someMethod("jhdajhajsha")
                         .someOtherMethod("sakjsaksja");
```

How do I prevent this?

Comment: I'm sure there's a setting, but it's typically good practice to line-break like that. It means most people can read your code without scrolling

Answer (score 4):

Good practice is to place line-break like that.
Any way you can edit you format setting

```
Window > Preferences
```

It will show the Preferences Window
In that Expand the `Java` then `Code Style` and select `Formatter`
Here you can edit `Active profile`
In the edit, `Line Wrapping` tab, The `General Settings` there is a option to set the
`Maximum line width` give the maximum limit here, When you format, it will break the line more than this limit

Answer (score 1):

windows > preferences > java > code style > formatter

Create a new profile. in the profile setting, select Line Wrapping [tab]

disable line wrapping for all . (class declaration, constructor declaration etc etc etc.. )